# An error occured while registering ocx files?

Tags: windows, command-line, activex, ocx

I created an ActiveX control ocx file using Visual Studio 2008.
Then tried registering the ocx file from command prompt "regsvr32 filename.ocx"

It gave an error saying "Load Library(filename.ocx) failed- The application has failed to start because configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem."

The Visual Studio builds the ocx file successfully. I tried registering this ocx file on other computers it worked. On my comp I am using Win XP SP3.

So where does the problem lie; is it in the "regsvr32" or something else is corrupt or missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) walker may help.

- Open the ocx and see if all dependnencies are fulfilled

If this look O.K.

- Open regsvr32.exe in dependnency walker and use Profile. Put your ocx as parameter to regsvr32 and see if some runtime problem occures.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, a dependency of your ocx file is missing on your computer. Try rebuilding all the dependencies and the re-register it.